# Factoring Integers the fun way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, functional-programming, rational-numbers

Code dump:

```
function factor(n) {
    function count(a) {
        if (a.length == 0) {
            return [];
        } else {
            var x = a.pop();
            var l = count(a);
            if (l[x] == undefined) {
                l[x] = 0;
            }
            l[x]++;
            return l;
        }
    }
    function decomp(comp, fac) {
        if (comp == 1) {
            return [];
        }
        if (fac == 1) {
            return [ comp ];
        }
        if (comp % fac == 0) {
            return decomp(fac, fac - 1).concat(decomp(comp / fac, fac));
        } else {
            return decomp(comp, fac - 1);
        }
    }
    return count(decomp(n, n)).map(function(a, b) {
        return [ b, a ];
    }).filter(function(a, b) {
        return a[1];
    }).map(function(a, b) {
        return "" + a[0] + "^" + a[1];
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + " * " + b;
    }).replace("^1", "");
}
```

It's mainly because I've been into functional programming lately that I tried a loopless, stateless, functional algorithm; I know that this example is absolutely facetious and that no one would do this in real life. That said, are there ways I can make this:

1. More efficient (e.g. less data),
2. More concise (which keeping the cool functional aspect), or
3. More functional (in a good way) in paradigm?

Comment: No source comments, names don't seem very good (count returns an array?)

Answer (score 4):

- Keystrokes are (almost) free. It's not like `decomp` looks any better than `decompose`. (Moving forward, I'm going to assume you made the rename.)
- Your `count()` function is cute. For extra fun, you could replace it with `Array.reduce()` (which you may know as `foldl`):

  ```
  decompose(n, n).reduce(function(accumulator, value) {
      if (typeof accumulator[value] === "undefined") {
          accumulator[value] = 0;
      }
      accumulator[value]++;
      return accumulator;
  }, []).map ...
  ```

  (The logic can be reduced to `prev[cur]++ || (prev[cur] = 1)` or `prev[cur] = prev[cur] + 1 || 1` if desired.)
- It's worth mentioning that comparisons against `undefined` are typically done with `===`.
- You've got a redundant `else` in `decompose()`.
- You can use `switch(true)` syntactic sugar to make `decompose()` prettier:

  ```
  function decompose(composite, factor) {
      switch(true) {
          case composite == 1:
              return [];
          case factor == 1:
              return [composite];
          case composite % factor == 0:
              return decompose(factor, factor - 1).concat(decompose(composite / factor, factor));
          default:
              return decompose(composite, factor - 1);
      }
  }
  ```

  or alternatively, chained conditional operators (commonly called ternary operators):

  ```
  function decompose(composite, factor) {
      return composite == 1 ? [] :
             factor == 1 ? [composite] :
             composite % factor != 0 ? decompose(composite, factor - 1) :
             decompose(factor, factor - 1).concat(decompose(composite / factor, factor));
      }
  }
  ```
- `decompose(n, n)` is ugly. Maybe you rewrite the contract of `decompose` to `int (maybe int) -> array`?
- You're replacing only the first instance of `^1`. You'll want to do `.replace(/\^1/g, "")` instead.
- `factor(1)` doesn't return `1` as expected. You can fix this by switching your first two `if`s.
- `factor(0)` recurs infinitely.
- You're using a lot of functions at the end there.

Here's my rendition. It's a little bit less elegant with the return... oh well. I'm using a utility function `when` to avoid potentially ugly ternary nesting. The double `reduce` bugs me but I can't think of a better way right now.

```
function factor(n) {
    function when(condition, string) {
        return condition ? string : "";
    }

    function decompose(composite, factor) {
        return factor === undefined ? decompose(composite, composite) :
               factor <= 1 ? [composite] :
               composite <= 1 ? [] :
               composite % factor != 0 ? decompose(composite, factor - 1) :
               decompose(factor, factor - 1).concat(decompose(composite / factor, factor));
    }

    return decompose(n).reduce(function(accumulator, value) {
            accumulator[value] = accumulator[value] + 1 || 1;
            return accumulator;
        }, []).reduce(function(accumulator, value, index) {
            return accumulator + when(value, " * " + index + when(value > 1, "^ " + value));
        }, "").substr(3);
}
```